# App Store "Updates Available" notification pops up despite having notifications turned off?

Tags: macos

On macOS 12.0.1, in System Preferences > Notifications, I have `App Store` turned off.

Yet, my computer just rudely blurted out a sound effect and popped up "Updates Available Do you want to install the updates now."

How can I turn this off or at the very least make the sound muted?[image]

Comment: Patrick, Could you please provide a screenshot of the System Preferences | Notifications where you have App Store turned off - because on my System Preferences Notifications, there is no option pertaining to the App Store.  A screenshot of the message itself would also be helpful, as on my Mac the message reminding me of the updates available is in a different section of the top menu bar, not part of the Notifications Centre.

Comment: @TechnoCat I added a photo of system preferences > notifications.  The notification itself is now long gone so I don't have a screenshot of it, but it was a little rectangle alert that popped up in the top right corner and played the loud and obnoxious sound that installer apps play when they're done installing, or when iTunes would finish importing / converting an audio file.

Comment: Patrick, my new 2021 MacBook Pro, which also has 12.0.1, has a notifications section that looks just like yours - but I don't get notifications with sound; if i could reproduce the problem I might have ideas on how to solve it.  Has your issue been resolved yet?

Comment: @TechnoCat no..  The problem persists whenever there are updates, obnoxious annoying alerts that I don't want interrupt what I am doing.  Apple should know when you're in full screen mode within an app, OBTRUSIVE OBNOXIOUS NOTIFICATIONS SHOULD NOT HAPPEN.