# Does anyone know the location of the notification "updates available" alert sound?

Tags: macos, notifications, sound-volume

I posted this question a while ago:
[App Store "Updates Available" notification pops up despite having notifications turned off?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/431444/app-store-updates-available-notification-pops-up-despite-having-notifications)

This is still driving me crazy and making me incredibly angry-- nothing is more obnoxious to me than my computer being hooked up to my large speakers, and in some random moment, it just blurting out at incredibly loud volume "DING DING DING!" as Mac OS is telling me App Store has updates available-- despite having notifications TURNED OFF for App Store (grrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr).

I want to find this stupid obnoxious audio file and ZERO IT OUT.

Comment: Are you still on the buggy 12.0.1? Have you thought about turning Notifications on for this then setting it to None? BTW, trying to change any system file or resource is not an easy task since Bug Sur.

Comment: yes ... 12.0.1.  I will try turning on and off again.  Pretty sure I did that a while ago though.

Comment: You really, really need to not be on 12.0.1. That itself can be blamed for most of the issues on Monterey. It's pointless trying to fight a bug that's probably been fixed 6 months ago.

Comment: ok @Tetsujin I updated to 12.3.1...  hopefully this no longer happens.